# How to measure reused or new connection per host for net/http using default transport

Tags: go

I have a rest api that connects to multiple downstream services. I have a transport like this using net/http

```
t := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).Clone()
t.MaxIdleConnsPerHost = 100
t.MaxIdleConns = 200
```

I want to measure how many new connections and how many reused connections per ost. Can someone please help. I will push it as a counter to prometheus using counter most probably

Comment: As @JimB suggested, you can check if connection was reused using the httptrace package like implemented here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/2825#issue-492263499